# get-help does not work in PS5 but does work in PS7

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0, powershell-7.0

I'm working on some PowerShell code that used to work and has broken. I noticed in PS5 when I run get-help against the below help section I receive:

`Get-Help : Get-Help could not find C:\PATH\program.ps1` in a help file in this session.

If I run the same thing in PS7, it works fine and returns help as expected. Is there a way to get powershell to tell me why it can't find the help?

```
<#
  .SYNOPSIS
    Add one or more hosts to an existing static group.

  .DESCRIPTION
    This script uses the OME REST API to add one or more hosts to an existing static group. You can provide specific
    devices or you can provide the job ID for a previous discovery job containing a set of servers. The script will pull
    from the discovery job and add those servers to a gorup. For authentication X-Auth is used over Basic Authentication.

    Note: The credentials entered are not stored to disk.

  .PARAMETER IpAddress 
    This is the IP address of the OME Appliance
  .PARAMETER Credentials
    Credentials used to talk to the OME Appliance
  .PARAMETER GroupName
    The name of the group to which you want to add servers.
  .PARAMETER DeviceIds
    A comma separated list of device-ids which you want to add to a group.
  .PARAMETER ServiceTags
    A comma separated list of service tags which you want to add to a group.
  .PARAMETER IdracIps
    A comma separated list of idrac IPs which you want to add to a group.
  .PARAMETER DeviceNames
    A comma separated list of device names which you want to add to a group.
  .PARAMETER UseDiscoveryJobId
    This option allows you to provide the job ID from a discovery job and will pull the servers from that job ID and
    assign them to the specified group. You can either retrieve the job ID programatically or you can get it manually
    from the UI by clicking on the job and pulling it from the URL.
    Ex: https://192.168.1.93/core/console/console.html#/core/monitor/monitor_portal/jobsDetails?jobsId=14026

  .EXAMPLE
    $creds = Get-Credentials
    .\Add-DeviceToStaticGroup.ps1' -IpAddress 192.168.1.93 -Credentials $creds -GroupName 'YourGroup' -IdracIps '192.168.1.45,192.168.1.63' -UseDiscoveryJobId 14094
#>
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [System.Net.IPAddress] $IpAddress,

    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [pscredential] $Credentials,

    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [String]$GroupName,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [Collections.Generic.List[int]] $DeviceIds,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [Collections.Generic.List[string]] $ServiceTags,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [Collections.Generic.List[string]] $IdracIps,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [Collections.Generic.List[string]] $DeviceNames,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [String] $UseDiscoveryJobId = $false
)
```

### PS5

[image]

### PS7

[image]

### `get-childitem` output

```
PS C:\Users\grant\Documents\code\OpenManage-Enterprise> gci .\PowerShell\Add-DeviceToStaticGroup.ps1


    Directory: C:\Users\grant\Documents\code\OpenManage-Enterprise\PowerShell


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----        2022/11/14      9:49          12435 Add-DeviceToStaticGroup.ps1
```

Comment: I see no issue, it works for me in both Windows PowerShell and PowerShell (Core).

Comment: Where is the PS1 file located. If it is not in your path environment variable and PS5 has a different default directory than PS7 this could be the reason.
Of course if you entered the full path on the Get-Help command this does not apply.

Comment: Added screenshots so you can see where everything is located and the difference I'm seing between PS5/PS7

Comment: What does `GCI .\PowerShell\Add-DeviceToStaticGroup.ps1` return?

Comment: @iRon Output added to the OP

Comment: In case you pasted the command, it could be an old en/em-dash problem (try to retype the command).